# Attachments & content text not sharing in Whatsapp

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the share_plus package version 7.2.1 in Flutter for file sharing. The Share.shareXFiles method works well for Gmail, but I'm facing issues with WhatsApp. Specifically, when trying to share both attachment files and text simultaneously, WhatsApp only sends the text, and the selected attachment files are not shared.

Additionally, if I attempt to share a single image attachment with text content, it works for WhatsApp sharing. However, when attempting to share multiple format attachments, it doesn't work.

```
Share.shareXFiles(
                                                xFileList,
                                                subject:
                                                    AppConstants.emailSubject,
                                                text: getMessageContent(
                                                  receipt: receipt,
                                                ),
                                              )
```

Comment: Please check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/75109067/19807154